# How to detect if hash key (#) is pressed in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I'm trying this code in my PreviewKeyDown event to detect if hash key (#) is pressed or not but it still show number (3) in my TextBox and MessageBox:-

```
    private void text_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.D3 && Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift)
            MessageBox.Show(e.Key.ToString());
    }
```

How can I modify or change this code to do what I need ?! 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`KeyDown` captures the last key that was pressed down, which was `Key.D3`, hence why you see `3` in your output. This is expected behavior.
Why would you want to use `e.Key.ToString()` though? This would make sense if you wanted to see which key is being pressed, but you are explicitly checking for the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> combo beforehand, so you already know what you're after.

```
// slightly modified your check
if (e.Key == Key.D3 && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) == ModifierKeys.Shift)
{
    MessageBox.Show("SHIFT+3 combo pressed");
}
```

Also, as [@keyboardP noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054686/how-to-detect-if-hash-key-is-pressed-in-wpf/39054878#comment65458830_39054878) in the comments, the location of the `#` sign on the keyboard depends on the layout of the keyboard itself (US/UK etc), or as you have it configured by your operating system. Perhaps you could add checking of the keyboard layout into the mix (might be worth having a look at the [`InputLanguageManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputlanguagemanager(v=vs.110).aspx) class from the `System.Windows.Input` namespace).

**EDIT**: As an alternative, why not just track whether the `#` character was input in the textbox, rather than checking for keyboard combos? It seems much more straightforward to me, though it depends on your requirements.

Comment: This will only work for keyboards where the hash key is on the number `3`. My UK keyboard has the hash key next to the enter button and is shared with the `tilde` key.

Comment: Same as mine, but I have the US layout configured in Windows. I agree with your remark and have updated my answer.